# How do I call an async dependency service from my xaml.cs code behind?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, dependency-injection, code-behind

I am overriding the `OnBackButtonPressed()` event in my code-behind because I add some custom navigation behaviour.

My target is to call a function from my bluetooth classic dependency service (specifically in .android) when I leave the current page by pressing the android back button (triangle). I disabled the navigation back arrow because the user already confirmed to be in a critical process and the user should not return unless he confirms it.
This dependency function is only called if I add a breakpoint inside the bluetooth function and delay further processes. Without a breakpoint the function call is skipped which makes me believe I got an error in assigning `await`/`async` and invoking threads.

The bluetooth command protocol I'm using to communicate with the device is not good but I can't change it. If I'd have programmed the bl classic controller I would've implemented proper set and get methods but there's no way to change that anymore. I wouldn't even use bl classic for that purpose...

**Code behind**
In my code behind I call a helper class which in return calls the dependency service. This function works as supposed to if I call it from my viewmodels.

```
    public partial class ProcessExecutionPage : ContentPage
    {
        public ProcessExecutionPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
        {
            Device.InvokeOnMainThreadAsync(async () =>
            {
                //Do some stuff with binding viewmodel which is working fine

                if (await DisplayAlert("Go back", "Go back?", "Yes", "No"))
                {
                    await BluetoothHelper.SetLockedAsync(false); //this function isn't called properly

                    base.OnBackButtonPressed();

                    //Do some stuff (updating db etc.) -> working fine

                    await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("MyNextPage"); //working fine
                }
            });
            return true;
        }
    }
```

**BluetoothHelper function** Here I'm getting my bluetooth device status and set it accordingly

```
public static async Task<bool> SetLockedAsync(bool status)
        {
            int delay = 300;
            System.Console.WriteLine("BluetoothHelper: SetLockedAsync(" + status.ToString() + ")");
            //Status check
            App.BluetoothService.Write("*");
            System.Console.WriteLine("Writing * - " + DateTime.Now.Millisecond.ToString());
            await Task.Delay(delay);
            
            int messageCounter = App.MessageList.Count;
            System.Console.WriteLine("messageCounter: " + messageCounter.ToString());
            App.BluetoothService.Write("*");
            System.Console.WriteLine("Writing * - " + DateTime.Now.Millisecond.ToString());
            await Task.Delay(delay);

            bool lockedStatus;
            System.Console.WriteLine("Getting lockedStatus - " + DateTime.Now.Millisecond.ToString());
            if (App.MessageList.Count > messageCounter) lockedStatus = false;
            else lockedStatus = true;

            System.Console.WriteLine("Check locked status");
            if (status != lockedStatus)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("Writing * - " + DateTime.Now.Millisecond.ToString());
                App.BluetoothService.Write("*");
                await Task.Delay(delay);
            }

            return true;
        }
```

Printing to console returns:

```
BluetoothHelper: SetLockedAsync(True)
Writing * - 167
Bluetooth: Listening received: 10
messageCounter: 7
Writing * - 507
Getting lockedStatus - 856
Check locked status
```

All `delay()` calls are skipped and the function isn't called asynchronous.
**EDIT:** This is wrong, I didn't check for milliseconds and the delays are working

**Interface**

```
public interface IBluetoothService
    {
        //...
        void Write(string text);
        //...
    }
```

**Android bluetooth implementation**

```
public class AndroidBluetoothService : IBluetoothService
    {
        /*private defines*/
        private BluetoothDevice device;
        private string connectedDeviceName;        
        private BluetoothSocket socket;
        private Stream outputStream;
        //...

        /*public defines*/
        public bool IsConnected { get; private set; }
        //...

        public void Write(string text)
        {
            if (!IsConnected || connectedDeviceName == string.Empty || device == null || socket == null) return;

            byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
            try
            {
                outputStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            }
            catch(System.Exception ex) { System.Console.WriteLine("Bluetooth: ERROR writing message: " + ex.Message); }
        }
```

- The bluetooth functions all work nicely when I use them from my MVVM.
- Debugger isn't showing any exceptions

Comment: As a test, replace `if (await DisplayAlert...)` with `if (true)`.  To see if that alert is somehow causing a problem. I mean, seems like somehow an issue with MainThread, considering how that could be.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve No I've tried right now and it's not the cause of the error

Comment: Ok. Perhaps some difference in timing, between the code in your VM (that successfully calls bluetooth), and the code you show here. When you say *"BluetoothHelper.SetLockedAsync"*, does that mean if you put a breakpoing on that line, it is never reached?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Yes it's a timing issue but actually I only reach that line of code if I put the breakpoints in the BluetoothHelper function. I think the `delay()` calls are skipped there and the function returns before I could receive an answer from my BL device. I'll try with printing to console now

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I've updated the question and included the console output of `SetLockedAsync()`

Comment: `WriteLine("Check locked status");` - print value of `lockStatus` also. Just to be sure. Also, what adds to `App.MessageList`? What is its value at start of `SetLockedAsync`? Sounds like its not incrementing at all during that method. Are you sure it did increment when using it from VM? Double-check that.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve App.MessageList is a List<string>, the line `Bluetooth: Listening received: 10` confirms there's something added to the list. I now believe the outputstream may not be working properly in this situation but I'm checking if there might be a workaround in my app which would give me a solution faster (eg calling `SetLockedAsync()` in the viewmodel of my `MyNextPage`

Comment: I'm now calling `SetLockedAsync(false)` from the `PageAppearingEvent` (xct:EventToCommand) in my viewmodel of `MyNextPage` which is a really dirty work around. I don't only call `MyNextPage` from the `ProcessExecutionPage` but also have other pages calling `MyNextPage`. Not posting this as an answer..